# Which is better in performance at these tables design?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have been asked to create something which tracks the daily cost to collect on images, and I am trying to figure out a database table schema that would boost this.

Company has over 1.3 million crawled products which is processed to be verified to be products to be 900K~1M.

Current database:
Courses 1-1 to CrawledCourses 1-n to CrawledCoursesImages

When crawledCourses can't be indexed in the search till they are verified,when verified=true it is copied to Courses indexed in search and images are accessed from crawledCoursesimages through crawledCourses

My issue with this is this table is going to get images slowly.
Two ideas are here to boost it a bit.

First method is more denormalized and create arrayfield to copy paths to images in where another database column will need to be added..
Second method is to add a foriegnkey to CrawledCoursesImages and get images from this relation.

Whick one of the two methods, which do you prefer? Why? Is there another alternative that you can think of which would handle this better?

The database is Postgresql
Another note: Images are not queried in all queries but most.
[image: This is a illustrated ERD]

Comment: Could you please try to describe the two designs in some more understandable way (like an ERD, some `CREATE TABLE` statements or otherwise)?

Comment: "When crawledCourses is verified, it is copied to Courses and images of accessed to crawledCoursesimages from crawledCourses" Can you please redefine this statement? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @dezso  It is edited, Be free for any questions , Thanks for your care

Comment: @Andrew Brennan It is edited, Be free for any questions , Thanks for your care

Comment: Why copy info from crawledcourses to courses? This will be very inefficient. Why not just have a courses table with an attribute of "verified"?

Comment: I'm new at the company, but Historical reasons 
We are not have to now, but that was required because of the first design of the system
We still can change this, but would be long migration journey now